# Heat kernel and estimates

Tags: pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-calculus, parabolic-pde

In the article by Hairer-Labbe (A simple construction of the continuum
parabolic Anderson model on $\mathbb{R}^2$), they used the following "well known" fact (picture below) in holder spaces.
[image]

I was wondering if this result appeared before and what other proofs were employed (I know that this fact is also proved in Gubinelli, Imkeller, Perkowski, paracontrolled distributions but in a different space) but I am looking for older proofs where the inequality holds in a **Holder** space.